# Can any DBMS send/receive huge matrices?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, lapack

I am trying to communicate [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) library and `.net` so I can do some processing outside a DBMS.

Is it possible to `send/receive` complete matrices as binary or as a direct memory pointers to process them? The main purpose is speed and avoid passing through a flat file.

- Is it possible that `Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL` support this technique?.
- What about libraries as `LAPACK`, can we export binaries or something to `.net`, or `c#`?
  (All through raw memory pointers or binaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is "huge" ?

You can store binary data as BLOBs. It can be used for images, audio, video, documents. Don't know if there is a 'native' format appropriate for lapack.

You can't give memory addresses as the data comes from disks and there's no guarantee whether Oracle will put them through process memory or shared memory, and either way it might reclaim that memory at any time or overwrite it with something else.

If you are talking C#/.Net, you are probably talking Windows which doesn't really allow memory to be shared between different processes anyway. Of course if the Oracle server is on a different machine from the .Net stuff, then you couldn't access memory from a remote machine anyway.

Comment: When referring huge I mean doing some processing, which DBMS is not designed for. So Is there any technique for this, as you described?

Comment: If using Linux, is there a way to shared memory or binaries?

Comment: External procedures can do it. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ex.htm

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but Oracle's package [UTL_NLA](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_nla.htm) can supposedly store a matrix with up to 1 million entries in a single VARRAY, which could then be passed to some other system relatively easily.

From the docs: "The UTL_NLA package exposes a subset of the BLAS and LAPACK (Version 3.0) operations on vectors and matrices represented as VARRAYs."

Comment: Good reading here http://oracledmt.blogspot.com/2007/04/way-cool-linear-algebra-in-oracle.html and ... all processing is done in the database. No passing over to the client as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, you can't.
SQL databases, Oracle included return sets of data and they can contain binary data in a column of that set. Within such a blob can be any format of almost any size. What processing needs to be done on the client?
If this is some kind of statistical analysis, check the Oracle analytical functions. They are VERY powerful and it will be very hard for any client to beat that.

Comment: Yes the purpouse is to do statistical analysis. But if so, How would you efficiently communicate DBMS with some mathematic libraries to do the processing even paralelizing some processes and then get the result in DBMS (DBMS is not designed to do some stuff like statistics)?

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question, explaining your data and the analysis that is to be performed upon it. The data is in the rdbms, Oracle also uses lots of parallelism on that data. It saves a lot of network round trips. A few examples are here <http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html>. Also look for the model clause that effectively gives you spreadsheet like calculations. VERY powerful.